# Small and resilient

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry, literature

At the same time I can be low or high,
I can be found where the ground meets the sky.

I may have a bald spot on top of my head,
but pick a fight with me, and you may be dead.

Slow moving, slow growing, I eventually change,
but I'll always have friends out on the range.

What am I?

Part 2 of the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> A mountain

At the same time I can be low or high, I can be found where the ground meets the sky.

> Mountains can be seen on the horizon; some of them are low (usually older mountains, which have eroded), some high (usually younger ones)

I may have a bald spot on top of my head, But pick a fight with me and you may be dead.

> Snow-capped peaks are something you see on mountains high enough - these resemble a "bald spot" on the top of someone's head. But people who climb mountains—seen as a challenge or fight—could "lose the fight" often die.

Slow moving, slow growing, I eventually change, But I'll always have friends out on the range.

> Mountains change very slowly, from parts of the earth moving as well as erosion; mountains are found in "ranges", that is, a bunch of them all together.

Comment: Ding ding ding. We have a winner! Part 3 tomorrow. But you didn't cover the last line. It's a pretty easy one. ;)

Comment: @Z.Dailey The "range" bit? If so, I just added a little. Let me know if that's enough or if you need more.

Comment: Yah. You got it. And quick too. Didn't want a complaint for being too vague. But this is what happens when I make it a little easier. Next one will be hard again.

Answer (score 2):

You could be

> the sun.

At the same time I can be low or high, I can be found where the ground meets the sky.

> During the day, the sun will be at different places.

I may have a bald spot on top of my head, But pick a fight with me and you may be dead.

> Do fly to close to the sun. I have trouble getting the bald spot to fit.

Slow moving, slow growing, I eventually change, But I'll always have friends out on the range.

> The sun will eventually turn into another stellar body when the hydrogen runs out (is transformed). There are several sun-like bodies in the universe, for instance Alpha Centauri.

Comment: This is actually what my IRL friends all guessed at first.